# How do I make vim my editor of choice for git notes?

Tags: git, vim

Is there any way to use vim to edit git notes?  At the moment all I have is the `git notes add -m` command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's configured the same way as for any other git command that invokes an editor.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

> `core.editor`
>   By default, Git uses whatever you’ve set as your default
>   text editor or else falls back to the Vi editor to create and edit
>   your commit and tag messages. To change that default to something
>   else, you can use the `core.editor` setting:
>
> `$ git config --global core.editor emacs`
>    Now, no matter what is set as
>   your default shell editor variable, Git will fire up Emacs to edit
>   messages.

Just specify `vim` rather than `emacs`.

You can also use the `$GIT_EDITOR`, `$VISUAL`, or `$EDITOR` environment variable (the latter two are used by a number of commands, not just Git).

Answer (score 6):

`git config --global core.editor "vim"`